# Optimization in complex vector space

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the following question
$$ \max_{  \mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{C}^N } \ f(\gamma)$$
$$\textrm{s.t.}  \ \gamma(\mathbf{w})=a|\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{w}|^2$$
$$\|\mathbf{w}\|^2\leq b,$$
$$|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{w}|^2 \leq \delta, \ k\in\{1,...,K\},$$
where $f$ is a non-decreasing real function and $\mathbb{C}^N$ is the set of complex vectors. Both $\mathbf{h}$ and $\mathbf{g}_k$ are complex vectors and $a,b,\delta$ are positive real.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $|\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{w}|^2\leq \|\mathbf{h}\|^2 \|\mathbf{w}\|^2$, and the inequality becomes an equality iff $\mathbf{w}=\alpha\mathbf{h}$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, to optimize $\alpha$, I set it to $\alpha^*=\min\big( (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2}, (\frac{b}{\|\mathbf{h}\|^2})^{1/2} \big)$. This gives a feasible solution. But how do I prove that this is the optimal solution? I tried contradiction but it didn't go anywhere.

Edit: I have tried the following. For contradiction, suppose there exists $\mathbf{w}'\neq \mathbf{w}:=\alpha^*\mathbf{h}$ such that $\gamma(\mathbf{w})<\gamma(\mathbf{w}')$. We have
$$\gamma(\mathbf{w})=a(\alpha^*)^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 < \gamma(\mathbf{w}')=a|\mathbf{h}\mathbf{w}'|^2\leq a\|\mathbf{h}\|^2\|\mathbf{w}'\|^2 \leq ab\|\mathbf{h}\|^2$$
Hence,
$$(\alpha^*)^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^2<b.$$
This means that the condition $\gamma(\mathbf{w})<\gamma(\mathbf{w}')$ can hold if
$$(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} < (\frac{b}{\|\mathbf{h}\|^2})^{1/2}. \ \ (*)$$
The inequality above also implies (by Cauchy-Schwarz) that
$$(\frac{\delta}{\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\|^2})^{1/2} < ( b )^{1/2}. \ \ (**)$$
In that case, $\mathbf{w}=(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} \mathbf{h}$ and
$\gamma(\mathbf{w})= a (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^4$. For $\gamma( \mathbf{w}')> \gamma( \mathbf{w})$, we must have
$$\gamma(\mathbf{w})= a (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 <\gamma( \mathbf{w}')=a|\mathbf{h}\mathbf{w}'|^2 $$
or
$$ (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 < |\mathbf{h}\mathbf{w}'|^2 \leq \|\mathbf{h}\|^2\|\mathbf{w}'\|^2 $$
or
$$ (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|\mathbf{h}\|^2 <  \|\mathbf{w}'\|^2. $$
Let
$\|\mathbf{w}'\|:=(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} \|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon$
for some $\epsilon>0$. Let us now check the feasibility constraints to see if a $\mathbf{w}'$ defined with a magnitude as above violates any of them. The first feasibility constraint:
$$\|\mathbf{w}'\|^2=\big( (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} \|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon \big)^2
$$
$$=(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})\|h\|^2 + \epsilon^2 +2\epsilon (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2}\|h\|$$
From ($*$),
$$< b+\epsilon^2+2\epsilon b^{1/2}.$$
If we choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon\rightarrow  0$, we have $\|\mathbf{w}'\|^2\leq b$. Conversely, for contradiction, suppose we have $\|\mathbf{w}'\|^2\leq b$ for some $\epsilon \nrightarrow 0$. In that case
$$b\geq \|\mathbf{w}'\|^2=\big( (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} \|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon \big)^2
$$
$$\geq(\frac{\delta}{\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\|^2 \|\mathbf{h}\|^2})\|h\|^2 + \epsilon^2 +2\epsilon (\frac{\delta}{\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\|^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^2})^{1/2}\|h\|$$
$$=(\frac{\delta}{\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\|^2  })  + \epsilon^2 +2\epsilon (\frac{\delta}{\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\|^2 })^{1/2} $$
$$=\big( (\frac{\delta}{\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\|^2  })^{1/2}  + \epsilon \big)^2 $$
But in order for ($**$) to hold, we must have $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. (This part I'm not sure!) A contradiction. So, we can have a feasible $\mathbf{w}'$ with the magnitude $\big( (\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2} \|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon \big)$ iff $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Now, let's check the second feasibility constraint. Let's first define $\mathbf{w}':=(\beta\|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon)\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}$ where $\beta:=(\frac{\delta}{\max_k |\mathbf{g}_{k}^H\mathbf{h}|^2})^{1/2}$ and $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. Then, from the second feasibility constraint:
$$ |\mathbf{g}_k^H\mathbf{w}'|^2=|\mathbf{g}_k^H(\beta\|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon)\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}|^2$$
$$=\Big|\beta\|\mathbf{h}\|\mathbf{g}_k^H\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} + \epsilon\mathbf{g}_k^H\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} \Big|^2$$
$$\leq \Big| \big|\beta\|\mathbf{h}\|\mathbf{g}_k^H\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}\big| + \big|\epsilon\mathbf{g}_k^H\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} \big|\Big|^2 $$
$$ \leq \Big| \beta\|\mathbf{h}\| \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\| \frac{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} + \epsilon \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\| \frac{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} \Big|^2 $$
$$=\Big| \beta\|\mathbf{h}\| \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\|   + \epsilon \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\| \Big|^2 $$
$$= \Big| \delta^{1/2}\frac{\|\mathbf{h}\| \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\|}{(\max_k |\mathbf{g}_k^H\mathbf{h}|^2)^{1/2}}   + \epsilon \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\|  \Big|^2 $$
$$\leq \Big| \delta^{1/2}\frac{\|\mathbf{h}\| \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\|}{(\max_k \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\|^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^2)^{1/2}}   + \epsilon \|\mathbf{g}_k^H\|  \Big|^2 $$
$$\overset{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\leq \delta $$

So, now that $\mathbf{w}'$ satisfies the feasibility constraints, let's look at $\gamma(\mathbf{w}')$.
$$ \gamma(\mathbf{w}') = a|\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{w}'|^2
=a\Big|\mathbf{h}^H(\beta\|\mathbf{h}\|+\epsilon)\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}\Big|^2$$
$$=a\Big|\beta\|\mathbf{h}\| \mathbf{h}^H \frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}+\epsilon\mathbf{h}^H\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}\Big|^2$$
$$\leq  a\Big| \big| \beta\|\mathbf{h}\| \mathbf{h}^H \frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}\big| +\big|\epsilon\mathbf{h}^H\frac{\mathbf{w}'}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}\big| \Big|^2$$
$$\leq  a\Big| \beta\|\mathbf{h}\| \|\mathbf{h}^H\| \frac{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} +\epsilon\mathbf{h}^H\frac{\|\mathbf{w}'\|}{\|\mathbf{w}'\|} \Big|^2$$
$$\overset{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\leq  a\Big| \beta\|\mathbf{h}\| \|\mathbf{h}^H\|  \Big|^2$$
$$= a  \beta^2\|\mathbf{h}\|^4 = \gamma(\mathbf{w})$$
A contradiciton. Is this correct?